# After rebooting Ubuntu from USB, settings not saved

Tags: usb

After I started Ubuntu 12.04 from USB Stick I changed some Settings (display resolution, two monitors, etc) and made some updates.
When I restart my system all new settings are deleted and I get a completly blank system. Is it possible to save all the settings to USB or is it necessary to install ubuntu to HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the startup USB disk using Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator?

There's an option there (near the bottom) to store user documents and settings on the USB disk:

[image]

Comment: I made the USB under Win7 with Universal USB Installer, according to USB tutorial from Ubuntu  Website: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: At step 3 did you set a persistent file size for storing changes?

Comment: I used the same settings like Ubuntu Tutorial, so 0 MB for persistent file size. Do i only have to change this file size to save all settings and programs to USB, or do I have to change some settings in Ubuntu to use the USB as common device?
What is a good persistent file size for a 16 GB USB drive?

Comment: You'd need to set the persistent file size to a size greater than 0 MB to save any data. How much space you wish to set aside will depend on how much data you think you'll be needing to save. You should only need to change this setting in the tutorial.

Comment: Ok, I´ll try later this day. Thanks for your fast help!